# Javascript replace all duplicate characters in an array the same way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm replacing all characters in an array with random letters/numbers. However, duplicate letters do not get the same values which is what I want.

```
var rWords = ["all","ball","balloon"];
var word = rWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * rWords.length)];

var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
var getPos = function(arr) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
}

var arr = word.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    arr.splice(getPos(arr), 1, letters[getPos(letters)]);
}
word = arr.join('');
```

I want the output to be something like:
all = 4xx, ball = Y4xx, balloon = Y4xxRR1

Comment: It was this "duplicate letters do not get the same values" property which helped lead to the downfall of the [Enigma machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis_of_the_Enigma#Security_properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `map` function that return unique char for same input (for each character we want to replace we check if we already have a replacement for it stored in `_map`, if not then we find one and use it and store it in `_map` for future use)

```js
var rWords = ["all","ball","balloon"];

var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

var _map = {}
function map(char) {
    if (_map[char] === undefined) {
        _map[char] = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)]
    }
    return _map[char]
}
var result = rWords.map(function(word) {
    var arr = word.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        arr.splice(i, 1, map(arr[i]));
    }
    return arr.join('');
})

console.log(result);
```